# element.setAttribute('prop',value) vs element.prop = value

Tags: javascript, html, dom, cross-browser

We have a setAttribute method, for DOM elements.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.setAttribute

How is it different from using the below?

```
 domElement.propName = value
```

Is there any benefit to either approaches ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`domElement.setAttribute('propName', obj)` is setting an XML attribute, it will be converted into a string and added to the DOM tag.

`domElement.propName` is setting an expando property, it can be of any type. It's setting it on the JS object that wraps the DOM object implementation.

They do not have the same effect, unless you are dealing with an attribute that is recognized by the parser like `src,id,value`. Those properties get copied to the expando property but there are many rabbit holes and cases where it doesn't work reliably (usually when the expando doesn't take a string, like `onclick, checked`)

This example shows that they are different.

```
domElement.setAttribute('someProp', 5);
console.log(domElement.someProp); // undefined
domElement.someProp = 10; 
console.log(domElement.someProp); // 10
console.log(domElement.getAttribute('someProp')); // "5" -> it's a string
```

Always using DOM expando properties is less likely to cause trouble. The only case where you want to use setAttribute is when you need to serialize the node (using `outerHTML`) and you want that attribute to be reflected in the serialization

Comment: for example, var x = new Image(); Now we could do, x.src = "/abc.png" or we could do x.setAttribute('src','abc.png').  do you think either way does the exact same.

Comment: @sbr In the case of src, because it's an attribute that is recognized by the parser, and it's a string, it will work either way. However, it's preferred to do it using `img.src` (unless you need it back when serializing the DOM node, since `innerHTML/outerHTML` will not change the attribute when you only set the expando property)

Comment: From JS they do the same thing, @sbr...  But on the other hand: `var time = document.createElement("time"); time.pubdate = true; time.datetime = "2012-10-04T12:28:00.000Z"; time.getAttribute("datetime");` They are very different things and important for very different reasons if you're working with JS or working with HTML/DOM for your desired results. Only some nodes have getters and setters for some specific properties (like `src` and `href`). Most of the time, they serve two different purposes, and you can't use one way to do both things. Use the JS method for JS, and set attribute for HTML.

Comment: @Norguard Your comment is not really warranted under my answer, since I have already explained everything you've said.

Comment: The other problem with that is that different browsers provide different interfaces to different nodes. They aren't cross-browser standard (unless they're fundamentally important, like links). This is especially true for html5 APIs (especially new form elements), where some browsers will extend an attribute to a property (and vise versa), and other browsers will not. It's also true of some old browsers which wouldn't even let you assign your own object properties/methods to nodes, at all.

Comment: @Norguard, if you want to provide your own answer, do so, don't litter the comments here, hard to see how your comments are related to my answer

Comment: @JuanMendes Yes -- the last comment I noticed was `sbr`'s addendum for images, as a defense to his argument... I do a lot of typing on my cellphone.  My apologies.

Comment: In the case of the `src` expando property (in HTML5 terminology, the "IDL attribute") on the img element, it is reflected by the `src` XML attribute (in HTML5 terminology, the "content attribute") so setting img.src should (and does, at least in modern browsers) cause innerHTML/outerHTML to be updated appropriately.

Comment: @Alohci Here's evidence that you shouldn't use it if you need it to reflect in the HTML http://jsfiddle.net/3DNj4/1/ The difference is that the property is not a string

Comment: @JuanMendes - Yes indeed. The reflection of attributes varies wildly. In fact your comment on Joshua's answer about the value attribute was only partially true - on the input element it is the "defaultValue" IDL attribute that reflects the "value" content attribute, rather than the "value" IDL attribute.

Comment: Another thing I noticed in the source code of jquery attr method, they are using setAttribute.

Comment: My use case is mostly, operating on dom elements and operating on predefined attributes on these. so notdoing to do something like: domElement.setAttribute('customProp',value);

Comment: @sbr i don't see your point, it's pretty obvious that $.attr will work with setAttribute, for the same reason, you should use $.val() instead of $.attr('value'). I've already said it and explained why, use expandon properties, I'm not sure what else there is to explain